# How to Simplify this question?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

$$\begin{align}f(n+1) &= (n+2)! -1 = (n+2)(n+1)! - 1 \\
&= (n+2)\left((n+1)!-1\right) + (n+2) - 1 \\
&= (n+2) \cdot f(n) + (n+1)
\end{align}$$

I understand the first line but not how to get from line 1 to line 2?

Answer (score 0):

That's just the result of adding and subtracting $n+2$: $$\begin{align}
(n+2)(n+1)!-1&=(n+2)(n+1)!\color{brown}{-(n+2)+(n+2)}-1\\&=(n+2)((n+1)!-1)+(n+2)-1.\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you, where did you get (n+2) -1 from?

Comment: @ASoni Are you talking about how I moved from the first line to the second? If so then the answer is that I factored $(n+2)$ from $(n+2)(n+1)!-(n+2)$, and so $(n+2)-1$ will remain.